# SharedPreferences in AsyncTask got emoaty value

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, sharedpreferences

i have login activity and AsyncTask class .

so when Forward some values to log in activity to AsyncTask  .. and test it with toast msg i get null value in msg .

i have tested to use context and many ways but not working .

my sharedprefrences in loginactivity :

```
          SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString("logintemp", login1);
    editor.putString("passwordtemp", pass1);
    editor.apply();// commit is important here.
```

my code in doInBackground at  AsyncTask class :

```
  Activity mActivity;
  Context context ;

          SharedPreferences preferences =    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mActivity.getApplicationContext());
          String username = preferences.getString("logintemp","");

     Toast.makeText(mActivity.getApplicationContext(), username , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

when you retrieve username, you set the default value for when it cannot be found to "".
ANd inside your background task, you use  context.getSharedPresferences, but then you use mActivity.getApplicationContext()

I think there might be a conflict between the two or they represent different contexts

Answer (score 0):

`commit()` doesn't update in-memory values, instead it only updates the values on persistent storage. So if your API level is 10 then I would suggest you to use `apply()` which also updates the in-memory values.

```
//for example
editor.apply();
```

Comment: same result give empty value